# How to use yield call() putt() callback in side callback

Tags: react-native, redux, mqtt, redux-saga

I have generator function like

```
function* subscribe(action) {
  const topic = action.payload;

  client.subscribe(topic);
  yield put(MqttActions.onConnect(connected));
  client.onMessageArrived = (message) => {

    console.log('MESSAGE==',message.payloadString);
   //yield put(MqttActions.onMessageArrived(message));

  };
     yield put(MqttActions.onMessageArrived(client.onMessageArrived));

  client.onConnectionLost = (responseObject) => {
    console.log({ responseObject });
    //yield put(MqttActions.onConnectionLost(responseObject));


  };
}

export default function* mSagas() {
  yield all([fork(takeLatest, MqttActions.CONNECTING, connection)]);
  yield all([fork(takeLatest, MqttActions.SUBSCRIBE, subscribe)]); 

}
```

my issue here I am not able to yield put(MqttActions.onMessageArrived(message)) in side client.onMessageArrived = (message) => {} how to use yield here which can dispatch action when client.onMessageArrived happened , what is way to do this